# Continuous everyday workout and sudden drop in stamina, does it indicate a caloric deficiency?

Tags: exercise, calories, daily-caloric-intake

Good day folks,

I have been continuously working out (30-45 Minutes) everyday for the last 3 weeks and noticed a sudden drop in stamina for the last 3 days, i haven't changed my diet significantly.

I checked my blood pressure last night and noticed it to be 10 points lower than normal on both scales.

Fitbit heart rate readings indicate that i am not hitting the cardio zone as much in the last 3 days and yesterday was the worst.

- Feel tired than usual when working out.
- Had a dizzy spell after working out yesterday (Heart rate shows that i didn't hit the cardio zone at all)

are these signs of caloric deficiency or am i over excreting? or something else?

[image]

(I don't count calories)

Comment: Do you track your bodyweight? If you have not changed the way you exercise and not changed the way you eat, well, you must either have been in a really big deficit for all those weeks = lost weight or this is one of perhaps a thousand different options.

Comment: Aside from despising HR zones, I am guessing that working out every day for three weeks is a bit unusual for you? I would just suspect a bit of over-training, and you need a rest day or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you've either had a calorie deficit as you don't count calories it's impossible to judge how much you require vs how much youre intaking.

On top of this it could just be exhaustion. You've been training for 3 weeks straight without rest. It is important to get sleep and have rest days to focus on diet and recovery.